# Media Query Struggles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I'm working on making my site responsive and am having issues past the 1700px breakpoint.

[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTxCi.png)

Here's my html:

```
<div class="container-1">
<div class="header">
  <h2>OneDrive/ODB</h2><br><a class="one" href="#Anchor">Report a SharePoint bug here</a> 
 </div>
 <div class="table-col-1">
  <div class="border-1">
 <div class="table-head-1"> 
   <h1>Issues with OneDrive/ODB on the web?</h1>
  </div>
<div class="text-container">
 <p class="table-text">Post and vote on feature suggestions & improvements on UserVoice:</p> 
    <br><a href="#" class="button">ODC/ODB web</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS for previous breakpoint:

```
.table-col-1{
padding: 1.5em;
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;   
}

.table-head-1{
padding: 1.5em;
background-color: #515251;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.table-text{
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 18px;
padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.text-container{
padding-top: 1.5em;
padding-bottom: 3em;   
}

.border-1{
border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

My CSS for the breakpoint that's not working:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1700px) and (max-width: 4000px){
.table-head-1{
padding: 1.3em;
background-color: #515251;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
}
```

If I try and add a width, let's say 100%, to that or even to `.table-col-1` I get this [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmHQF.png).

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to that rule - this will include the padding in the 100% width which is otherwise added, summing up to 100% PLUS the given padding.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning width to 100% doesn't seem to work in this case because your code also adds extra padding to the div which is not needed.

So,can you please try changing the style properties of "**table-col-1**" to `padding: 1.5em 0em`; and `width to 100%`. A working example of this is here : https://jsfiddle.net/m70y6jnd/

Do let me know in comments below if this doesn't help you.

Comment: it does but I have 3 other identical divs next to this one and the 100% width is taking up that whole row